# Diagnosing SSH authentication failures when you don't have access to the client

Tags: ssh

We have just upgraded our Infoblox appliance and now the log shipment which occurs via scp is failing with auth issues.

Since this is an appliance and we have no access to the a shell on the box we are having trouble figuring out what is wrong.  On the infoblox end all we have in the configuration is hostname, port, username and password.  (no option for key :( )

I can invoke scp fine from another host with the credentials.

Any suggestions on finding out what the issue is?  (short of putting up a hacked sshd ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a "hacked" sshd.  You should be able to run sshd -ddd to put it into debug mode.

For example...

/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2222

...would listen on 2222 if you can direct client traffic to that port.  If not, stop the system sshd and start a debug listener to test the client with.

With any luck, the server-side debug will help you identify the authentication problem.

Comment: I found that you can also set `LogLevel DEBUG3` in sshd_conf